# blank value in first row of dropdown box

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I generated the data in dropdown box from postgresql database in php. The data is generated with empty first row in dropdown box and remaining row gives required data. I want to remove that empty first row. My code is like this

```
<select id="dzongkhag_id">
<option>Dzongkhag<option/>
<?php
$con_string= "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=bhutan_shp user=postgres password=rabi";
$db_con = pg_connect($con_string);
$result=pg_query($db_con,"SELECT * FROM dzongkhag");
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{echo"<option value={$row['dzgname']}>{$row['dzgname']}</option>";}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error defining html

In line Dzongkhag, you didn't close the option tag properly. That might be causing error.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you dont want to show the first array item, or empty arrays in general, right? so change this code:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{echo"<option value={$row['dzgname']}>{$row['dzgname']}</option>";}
```

to

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{
 if (empty($row)) continue;
 echo"<option value={$row['dzgname']}>{$row['dzgname']}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your non-empty values in your query itself. Try this,

```
 $result=pg_query($db_con,"SELECT * FROM dzongkhag where (`dzgname`!='' OR `dzgname` is not null ");
```

Comment: Blank space comes at the beginning of the dropdown box. I want to remove that blank space.